# Listing all Photoshop actions

Tags: .net, vb.net, photoshop, photoshop-script

I am trying to list all my actions in Photoshop.
This is the script i try to replicate [LINK](https://forums.adobe.com/message/7794542#7794542). But it always skip the last one.

So this part is listing my action groups. And in the loop I will list all actions. But that part fail also. I think that is how the flow of the code that is making error for me:

> The object "set 1 of set 2 of set 3" is not currently available.

Here is what i have came up with so far

```vb
 Dim actionSet As Integer = cTID("ASet")
 Dim action As Integer = cTID("Actn")
 Dim name As Integer = cTID("Nm  ")
 Dim numberOfChildren As Integer = cTID("NmbC")

 Dim refASet = New ActionReference()
 Dim refa = New ActionReference()

 Dim desc = New ActionDescriptor()
 Dim adesc = New ActionDescriptor()

 Dim index As Integer = 1
 While True
     refASet.PutIndex(actionSet, index)

     Try
         desc = _appPs.ExecuteActionGet(refASet)
     Catch ex As Exception
         Exit While
     End Try

     If desc.HasKey(name) Then
         Dim actions(desc.GetInteger(numberOfChildren)) As String
         MsgBox(desc.GetString(name))
     End If
     index += 1
 End While
```

Comment: I think you should inspect the Exception and do something sensible in place of simply exiting the While. You may be missing something there.

Comment: What happens if you initially set  `Dim index As Integer = 0`

Comment: Photoshop do not use stat value of index 0. First element is always ONE

Comment: Thought that might be the case.

Answer (score 2):

Well it was more simpler than i expected.

You have to reset the `ActionDescriptor` and `ActionReference` before you can call it again.

```
 Dim actionSet As Integer = cTID("ASet")
 Dim action As Integer = cTID("Actn")
 Dim name As Integer = cTID("Nm  ")
 Dim numberOfChildren As Integer = cTID("NmbC")

 Dim index As Integer = 1
 While True
     Dim desc = New ActionDescriptor()
     Dim refASet = New ActionReference()

     refASet.PutIndex(actionSet, index)

     Try
         desc = _appPs.ExecuteActionGet(refASet)
     Catch ex As Exception
         Exit While
     End Try

     If desc.HasKey(name) Then
         Dim actions(desc.GetInteger(numberOfChildren)) As String
         MsgBox(desc.GetString(name))
     End If
     index += 1
 End While
```